# Cannot set ListViewItem.IsSelected using ListView.ItemContainerStyle in WinRT

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

Trying to set the IsSelected Property for all items to be TRUE on a Multiple Select Mode ListView. I think I have the syntax correct. Any guesses as to what is wrong?

```
<ListView x:Name="myListView" SelectionMode="Multiple"  BorderThickness="1" 
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <Image Source="{Binding Thumbnail}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding dataSource.Name}"/>                    
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="True" />                    
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

Turns out this is not possible in WINRT

Workaround found @ http://pmichaels.net/2014/09/18/binding-isselected-method-in-the-listview-control-in-winrt/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have answered in comment for your another question, but still.

Unfortunately, bindings are not supported on Setters in WinRT. I think Silverlight only got them in version 5. For workarounds you basically could define an attached dependency property that sets up the binding for you. You can have a look here: [here](http://blog.onedevjob.com/2011/10/26/workaround-for-binding-not-supported-on-stylesettervalue-in-silverlight/)

Hope this helps!